# Untangling multiple issues in handling timezones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, timezone

An application is configured with a timezone that is not UTC.  It also sets

```
config.timezone = 'Bogota'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local`
```

The motivation is to have system timestamps set-up with the application's principle timezone.

The application however collects data of type datetime and the timezone where it occurred. Logged parameters are:

```
"event"=>{"name_last"=>"tz event", "date(3i)"=>"1", "date(2i)"=>"1", "date(1i)"=>"1987", "date(4i)"=>"01", "date(5i)"=>"01", "tz"=>"Hawaii"
```

The database has to distinct attributes: one for the datetime

```
    t.timestamptz "date"
    t.string "tz"
```

The goal is for users to be able to view the timestamptz attribute in the `tz` provided, **as well as** in UTC.

The problem is that the input is being processed as if it were in the appplication's configured timezone. *is it wiser to remove timezone configurations and work with UTC across the board?*

How can those parameters be processed to properly save the record with the input timezone in postgresql - taking into account potential daylight savings time - then viewed with both data representations (UTC and event's timezone) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you store points in time on the database should depend on whether the events they describe are timezone-dependent in nature or not. This makes a difference for events in the future, because the definition of a timezone may change after the event has been written to the database but before the event arrives.

Here is an example of a timezone-dependent event:

Assume that polling stations for the next general election open at 2025-09-21T08:00:00+02:00 in my time zone. But if my country abolishes daylight saving time before then, they will open instead on 2025-09-21T08:00:00+01:00 without an explicit rescheduling. In other words: The UTC time changes (from 2025-09-21T06:00:00Z to 2025-09-21T07:00:00Z), but the local time does not. Such an event should be stored with its local time (2025-09-21T08:00:00) and its timezone.

An example of a timezone-independent event would be the moment when an asteroid comest closest to the Earth.

Converting timezone-dependent events into other timezones is complicated, however, therefore it is *simpler* to store events in UTC, if that can be justified (for example, because they all lie in the past).

(Note, however, that timezone databases are sometimes updated even for years past, for example, after someone finds out that a region had introduced daylight saving time between 1835 and 1839, say.)

Comment: "...if that can be justified (for example, because they all lie in the past)"  is excellent.  For a date in the past, it is my understanding that postgresql has the mechanism to take into account DST, yes?

Comment: I am no postgresql expert, but https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT seems to take DST into account when converting UTC to a named timezone.