Convert local recurrence rule string to UTC recurrence Rule String for recurring events in Javascript
I am developing a calendar app and saving events in utc and handling timezone stuff on front-end. I am facing an issue that when I create a recurring string I select the days according to the local time but the date/time is being converted into utc but day is the same which is causing a lot of issues.
For example, my startDate is 29th as Pakistan standard Time but it will be 28th as per UTC. But the recurrene string is being genrated locally, such as FREQ=WEEKLY: DYDAY:FR, this is the string according to the local time but in utc It should be FREQ=WEEKLY: DYDAY:TH... I don't have any clue about that.
I have tried different methods but in vain.

Please show the code you tried

When people agree on a recurring appointment ("every Monday at 11am"), they typically expect the time to adapt to daylight savings time etc. For this reason, recurring (and, more generally, future) appointments are best not stored in UTC. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77162507/untangling-multiple-issues-in-handling-timezones.
